Selenium - Ventana "Mostrar notificaciones"
Estoy trabajando con Selenium y VB.NET. Al cargar el link de la web, esta muestra una notificación típica de la página, preguntando si se permite o no mostrar notificaciones. He tratado de marcar permitir, pero ninguna de las opciones ha funcionado.

Opción 1:
    Dim alert As IAlert = New WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
    alert.Accept()

Opción 2:
   Try
        Dim Alert As IAlert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert()
        Alert.Accept()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

Opción 3:
    Dim profile As Dictionary(Of String, Object) = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()
    profile.Add("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 1)

    Dim Options As Dictionary(Of String, Object) = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()

    Options.Add("prefs", profile)


La forma más practica que encontré, es deshabilitar las notificaciones del navegador:
https://webkul.com/blog/handle-browser-level-notification-using-selenium/
